# A program for creating LiveUSB

Tags: live-usb, unetbootin

Do you know any program which works on Linux like UNetbooting 
thanks

Comment: Unetbootin does already work on Linux. What's the question?

Comment: @int_ua The obvious interpretation is "What works on Linux like UNetbootin for Windows?" The answer: "UNetbootin for Linux." The meaning is clear and there are good answers; there's no reason to close this, *except perhaps as a duplicate if a suitable question can be found*. (I'm not saying you're necessarily one of the close-voters.)

Answer (score 1):

[Unetbootin](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unetbootin/) is already available for installation.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Ubuntu, you can 
[Create a USB Stick on Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu). But if you only have Windows, you can use [Pendrive Linux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) to create one.